# Django : refresh issue on selection field

Tags: django, django-forms, refresh, django-database

I have a choiceField called from a context_processors so it can appear in all of my site's pages. It provides the projects existing in a database. The problem is that it does not refresh correctly.
I deleted some records in my database and they still are in my selection. Also I'd like it to refresh automatically when a user creates a new project.

Here is my form and how I call it. If anyone has a suggestion, it would be appreciated.

forms.py:

```
class SelectForm(forms.Form):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(SelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.fields['project'].initial=[(p.proj_id, p.proj_name+"_"+p.proj_description) for p in Project.getProjectParent(Project())]


        project_choices = [(p.proj_id, p.proj_name+"_"+p.proj_description) for p in Project.getProjectParent(Project())]

        project = forms.ChoiceField(project_choices)

        def save(self):
                project = self.cleaned_data['project']
                src = ''
                p = {'proj': project, 'src': src}
                return p
```

context_processors.py :

```
def display_select_proj(request):
        if request.method == "POST" and (request.POST.get("action", "") == "Change"):
                form = SelectForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                        p = form.save()
                        proj = p['proj']
                        src = p['src']

                        request.session['proj'] = proj

        else:
                proj = request.session['proj']
                src = ""
                form = SelectForm(initial={'project': proj})

        return {'select_form': form, 'proj': proj, 'src': src}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to give the code for getProjectParent.

Comment: The code for project parent is just a sql query. It gives the same result for `p in Project.objects.all()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the first part move `project_choices` inside **init** so it is generated as the form is called, it will then update on refresh.

Comment: I tried: `super(SelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                project_choices = [(p.proj_id, p.proj_name+"_"+p.proj_description) for p in Project.objects.all()]
                self.fields['project'].initial=project_choices` in the init fonction. And then call `project=forms.ChoiceField()` And now it doesn't give me anything at all in the choiceField

Comment: its needs to be set as choices add self.fields['project'].choices = project_choices